# Xamarin forms (ios): no results for NEHotspotHelperCommand networklist wifi scan

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Using a dependency service in Xamarin forms (in the iOS part to be specific), I am trying to programmatically scan for nearby wifi networks which should be possible, according to this [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/Hotspot_Network_Subsystem_Guide/Contents/CommandHandlingDetails.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016639-CH4-SW2).
This is my code which is called upon a button click inside the ios part of the dependency service:

```
NetworkExtension.NEHotspotHelperCommand myHelper = new NetworkExtension.NEHotspotHelperCommand(); //never returns any results
NetworkExtension.NEHotspotNetwork[] myArray; //remains empty

public void StartScan(){ //even called this several times to give myArray time to get results

   myArray = myHelper.NetworkList; //also tried to initilize on class level
   if( myArray != null ){ //never called
      foreach( var item in myArray){
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( $"Data: {item}" );
      }
   }
}
```

For some strange reason, I never get any results - Networklist always remains null. No networks are found whatsoever. I set all permissions that are even remotely associated to communication and WiFi and applied for permission to use NEHotSpotHelper class at Apple (no response yet). My questions:

1) Is my problem code related, in a manner that I may have missed some sort of init() function or something similar? Apple docs in this concern can only be described as poor.

2) Am I simply unable to read any values for NetworkList as long as I am not granted permission by Apple to use NEHotSpotHelper class and recreated my Certificates and Provisioning Profiles?

What else might be the problem? I am running out of ideas.